# How to fix grub menu entry for Windows 11

Tags: boot, grub

I have Win11 and Manjaro systems. I manually added menu entry for Win11 into `40_custom` grub's config (MS's and linux EFIs are on the different partitions):

```
menuentry 'Windows 11' {
  insmod ntfs
  set root=(hd1,1)
  search --no-floppy --set-root --fs-uuid A44E-6E73
  chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

When I select to load this entry from grub menu I get an error:

```
Booting a command list
error: no such device: --set-root.
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a06785,0)\PCI(0,e)/UnknownMessaging(17)/HD(1,800,32000,d1187765595568,2,2)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire
```

Windows loads correctly after this error, but I want to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your menuentry, `--set-root` should be `--set=root`